# Foreach and columns

Tags: php, html, foreach

```
<?php
$arr = range(1,rand(40,120)); ?>

<table>

<?php
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
} ?>

</table>
```

This generate for me for example:

```
1
2
3
...
111
```

all in one columns. How can i make - when in first column are 25 rows then create new column, etc. For example:

```
1   26  51
2   27  ...
3
..
25  50
```

How can i make it?
I can use DIV instead of table.

Comment: Can you assemble the desired table manually, with just html?

Comment: No, i must use foreach with PHP

Comment: Do not use `&$value` unless you need it. And in this case `unset()` it **right after the loop**.

Comment: @Mark Fondy: no no, I just was asking if you can to do that manually - then you can think of an algorithm of doing so by php.

Comment: @MarkFondy - Check my answer below. It's tested and works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php      
$arr = range(1,rand(40,120)); 
?>      

<div style="width:40px; float:left;">      

<?php      
foreach ($arr as $value) {      
    echo $value . '<br />';  
        if ($value % 25 == 0) {
            echo '</div><div style="width:40px; float:left;">';
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: First, he said at the end of his question that he could use divs instead of tables. Second, the rows are irrelevant when it comes to width. As for columns, the width specified is of each column, not overall, so it doesn't matter how many columns ther are, and with this narrow dataset (40-120 numbers), I didn't see harm in specifying a width of the column to make it look nice. His question was about how to get it into columns, not design. I suppose you could replace width with something like margin: 0 15px 0 0; if you're worried about spacing being even.

Answer (score 1):

Vertically sorted columns of that sort (no pun intended) are a serious pain in html, since this arragement is a "top->bottom, left->right", while HTML tables by their nature are "left->right, top->bottom" instead.

To get around it, you have to do some offset math on the array indexes, so you can output by rows:

```
$arr = range(1,rand(40,120));
$rows = ceil(count($arr) / 3); // assuming 3 columns
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    echo <<<EOL
<tr>
   <td>{$arr[$i]}</td>    1, 2, 3, etc...
   <td>{$arr[$i+rows]}</td>  11, 12, 13, etc...
   <td>{$arr[$i+(2*$rows)]}</td> 21, 22, 23, etc...
</tr>
EOL;
}
```

This code probably won't work as is, but should give you the basic idea.

Comment: Like you said, this doesn't work as it 1. only creates three columns, 2. creates empty TDs (which doesn't really break the code, but it's unnecessary), and why are you echoing EOL??

Comment: Aight, thanks. Never used it, or heard of it before. Can see why some people do though

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

```
<?php

$rows = 25;
$arr = range(1, rand(40, 120));
$arr = array_merge($arr, array_fill(0, $rows - (count($arr) % $rows), null));
$cols = ceil(count($arr) / $rows);
$render = array();

echo '<table>' . "\n";
foreach ($arr as $i => $value) {
  $render[$i % $rows][] = $value;
  if (count($render[$i % $rows]) == $cols) {
    echo '  <tr>' . "\n" . '    <td>' . implode('</td>' . "\n" . '    <td>', $render[$i % $rows]) . '</td>' . "\n" . '  </tr>' . "\n";
  }
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";

?>
```